# Shell Script on date filter

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file having multiple lines in the following order

```
Name=abc Date=12/10/2013
Name=xyz Date=11/01/2014
Name=pqr Date=06/30/2014
Name=klm Date=07/08/2014
```

And so on. Date format is mm/dd/yyyy.

I want to write a shell script, which will traverse each line and it should return me the line, whose `Date` is about to come in next 1 week. Like here, if I run the script today, it must return me

```
Name=pqr Date=06/30/2014
```

How to achieve that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? One hint I can give is that using the `date` command you can output a time using relative offsets like `date --date="+1 week"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Get today's date in natively sortable format: YYYYMMDD
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
# Get next week's date in natively sortable format: YYYYMMDD
oneweek=$(date -d "+1 week" +%Y%m%d)

# Pass the start and end dates to awk as variables.
# Use `=` as the awk delimiter.
# Split the third field on `/` to convert the date to the natively sortable format.
# Compare converted date to start and end values (as an `awk` pattern so true results use the default `awk` print action).
awk -v start=$today -v end=$oneweek -F= '{split($3, a, /\//)} (a[3] a[1] a[2] > start) && (a[3] a[1] a[2] < end)' file
```

Comment: I tried to print the oneweek `oneweek=$(date -d "+1 week" +%Y%m%d)`...... it showed me a warning `date: illegal option -- d`...... :(

Comment: date is not a shell built-in (unless ksh has one for it) so the shell doesn't matter, but the version of the date utility does. I was using `GNU coreutils` date. It would seem the `AIX` date does not have that flag. Perhaps it has the long `--date` option instead?

Comment: I tried `--date` option also, but it didn't work..... I was not able to see the version of date also in my AIX by `date --version`...... Though all working good in Linux machine

Comment: @user3772505 What version of awk are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is get date from each line and convert it to seconds from Epoch time and compare as shown below.

while read line

do

```
   date_in_line=`echo $line | awk -F= '{print $NF}'`
   date_after_1_week_in_sec=$(date -d "+1 week" +%s)
   date_in_line_sec=$(date -d $date_in_line +%s)

   if [ $date_in_line_sec -lt $date_after_1_week_in_sec ]; then
           echo $line
   fi
```

done < file.txt

Hope it helps.